# Retreiving an object id from a queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, primary-key

I have a contract table in my database, the contracts are based mainly on a listing and two users. When creating the contract I want to check if the contract already exists and if so redicrect the user(s) to the created contract. Here is the code in my view:

```
def create_proposal (request, conversation_pk):
existing_proposal = Contract.objects.filter(users__in=[user_1, user_2]).filter(listing_id=listing).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Then I redirect using:

```
    if existing_proposal.exists():
    messages.success(request, "the proposal already exists")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('agreement:agreement', kwargs={'pk': existing_proposal[0].pk}))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError at /en/agreement/create_proposal/32
'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values_list` returns a list of values, so you don't have a queryset when you evaluate the expression, you literally have a list of primary keys. You'd use this when you want to pull in say, just a field of a model and iterate over it to do some sort of evaluation. The workhorse of finding the existing proposal here is done by the `filter` statements.

Since you're assuming there is one (and only one match), better to do:

`existing_proposal = Contract.objects.filter(users__in=[user_1, user_2]).filter(listing_id=listing).only('id').first()`

This returns the first `Contract` object that meets your filter criteria, pulling in its `id` which is all you need for a redirect to it.

Then for the assignment in your redirect:

`{'pk': existing_proposal.pk}`

The `only` is optional but, hey, why not optimize the call?

Comment: If I use only(id), then the existing_proposal's existence cannot be verified. Should I then create one value list and another for the id? or can I combine the value_list and the only?

Comment: Er, why? You'll have already filtered on those fields, `only` is just shaping the `SELECT` statement that underlies the query. If your filter retrieved the proposal, then it exists and all you need it the PK/ID for the redirect.

I mean, if the `only` bothers you, by all means drop it. It's a tiny optimization unless your model has some very large fields.

Comment: It is really weird, but changing the code to the one mentioned bove, I am getting 'code' 'Contract' object has no attribute 'exists' 'code'

Comment: Drop the `exists()`. `first` returns an object or `None` so just test for existence: `if existing_proposal:`

Comment: Sorry @Benjamin for the hassle, but I am getting: 'Contract' object does not support indexing, the users are actually MAnytoMany field, can this be the reason?

Comment: Unlikely. I am guessing that you still have `existing_proposal[0].pk` in your code. Just pull out the subset because you have a `Contract` object, not a Queryset.

Comment: My mistake, sorry :), thank you again for your time!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!